# Excel like filtering in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to jquery and jqGrid. I am struggling with it.I need someone to help me in the JqGrid that I need a filtering headers in the jqGrid.I look for it when I found a [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ButtonsInTheColumnHeaders.htm) done by Oleg. But I need checkbox when I select on checkbox search values have to to be filtered just like Excel Filtering.Please help me out someone.

Even I findout the [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016109/jqgrid-any-easy-way-to-implement-undo-on-excel-like-jqgrid-implementation) but that is not working to me.Please help me in it,as I need it badly.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't like words like "Excel like filtering" because everybody interprets it in different way. So I have to answer in the way how I interpret it.

I think that you should use jQuery UI [MultiSelect Widget](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) written by [Eric Hynds](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/). I wrote some answers and demos before which shows how to use it.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe.htm) shows how to use jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget together with [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) to implement "Excel like filtering".

[image]

By the way you can build the list of values displayed by the multiselect widget dynamically like the values of jQuery UI Autocomplete in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935).

Another answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851429/315935) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9999761/315935)) with the corresponding demos ([this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultipleCheckboxEdit.htm) and [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithMultselect.htm)) shows how to use the widget for editing.

**UPDATED**: [The updated demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simplelocalgridwithsearchingtoolbarmultilpe1.htm) uses jqGrid 4.4.1, jQuery UI 1.8.24 and jQuery 1.8.2 and the current (version 1.13.6 from 29.09.2012) version of jQuery UI Multiselect downloaded from [github](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/).

**UPDATED 2**: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26949859/315935) contains `beforeClear` callback of `filterToolbar` which is required in case of usage "Refresh" button. The answer contains the updated demo which uses jqGrid 4.6.0.

Comment: @user1268130 I posted the demo which is updated to the current version of jqgrid: see **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: @Mohammad: the demos from my answer contains full JavaScript code inside of HTML page. So you need just open the demo in any web browser. Then you can open context menu by clicking right mouse and you choose the item like "View page source".

Comment: is this available to even jqgrid php?

Comment: @HelloMan: You mean probably Guriddo Suito PHP? I don't use personally commercial products based on original pure JavaScript version of jqGrid. So it's difficult to say how you can do this, but I'm sure that if could be possible because it's based on the same JavaScript code. You will need to include your own code in somewhere in `dataInit` part.