# JQGrid jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget together with toolbar searching not working in Internet Explorer [8]

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, jqgrid, multi-select

I'm trying to get this [Excel like filtering in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869819/excel-like-filtering-in-jqgrid) working in internet explorer 8. It's works fine in Chrome but in Internet Explorer the rows are somehow filtered out by the code. If I'm not using the JSon data and copy the local data from the [oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) example all seems to work fine...
My target browser is IE 8, need to use JSon data and am using JQgrid 4.4.1 and multiselect 1.13.6. 
Help is much appreciated :-)

**Update**
After several refreshes it works sometimes in IE. Can it have something to do with the JSon data loading time?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var scannamenlijst = '@ViewBag.scannamenlijst';

    //<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint unparam: true, plusplus: true, browser: true */
    $(function () {

            $grid = $("#list"),
            myDefaultSearch = "cn",
            getColumnIndexByName = function (columnName) {
                var cm = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                    if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                        return i; // return the index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            },
            modifySearchingFilter = function (separator) {
                var i, l, rules, rule, parts, j, group, str, iCol, cmi, cm = this.p.colModel,
                    filters = $.parseJSON(this.p.postData.filters);
                if (filters && filters.rules !== undefined && filters.rules.length > 0) {
                    rules = filters.rules;
                    for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                        rule = rules[i];
                        iCol = getColumnIndexByName.call(this, rule.field);
                        cmi = cm[iCol];
                        if (iCol >= 0 &&
                                ((cmi.searchoptions === undefined || cmi.searchoptions.sopt === undefined)
                                    && (rule.op === myDefaultSearch)) ||
                                (typeof (cmi.searchoptions) === "object" &&
                                    $.isArray(cmi.searchoptions.sopt) &&
                                    cmi.searchoptions.sopt[0] === rule.op)) {
                            // make modifications only for the 'contains' operation
                            parts = rule.data.split(separator);
                            if (parts.length > 1) {
                                if (filters.groups === undefined) {
                                    filters.groups = [];
                                }
                                group = {
                                    groupOp: 'OR',
                                    groups: [],
                                    rules: []
                                };
                                filters.groups.push(group);
                                for (j = 0, l = parts.length; j < l; j++) {
                                    str = parts[j];
                                    if (str) {
                                        // skip empty '', which exist in case of two separaters of once
                                        group.rules.push({
                                            data: parts[j],
                                            op: rule.op,
                                            field: rule.field
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                                rules.splice(i, 1);
                                i--; // to skip i++
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    this.p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify(filters);
                }
            },
            dataInitMultiselect = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var $elem = $(elem), id = elem.id,
                        inToolbar = typeof id === "string" && id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_",
                        options = {
                            selectedList: 2,
                            height: "auto",
                            checkAllText: "all",
                            uncheckAllText: "no",
                            noneSelectedText: "Any",
                            open: function () {
                                var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                                $menu.width("auto");
                                return;
                            }
                        },
                        $options = $elem.find("option");
                    if ($options.length > 0 && $options[0].selected) {
                        $options[0].selected = false; // unselect the first selected option
                    }
                    if (inToolbar) {
                        options.minWidth = 'auto';
                    }
                    $elem.multiselect(options);
                    $elem.siblings('button.ui-multiselect').css({
                        width: inToolbar ? "98%" : "100%",
                        marginTop: "1px",
                        marginBottom: "1px",
                        paddingTop: "3px"
                    });
                }, 50);
            };

        $grid.jqGrid({
            url: '/Stakeholder/getscanresponses/',
            mtype: 'POST',
            datatype: "json",
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows", //array containing actual data
                page: "page", //current page
                total: "total", //total pages for the query
                records: "records", //total number of records
                repeatitems: false,
                //id: "initiatiefid" //index of the column with the PK in it
            },

            colNames: ['Initiatief', 'Respondent', 'Scan', 'Datum'],
            colModel: [
                //{name:'id',index:'id',width:70,align:'center',sorttype: 'int'},
                { name: 'initiatiefnaam', index: 'initiatiefnaam', width: 165 },
                { name: 'respondentnaam', index: 'respondentnaam', width: 165 },
                {
                    name: 'scannaam',  width: 200, align: 'center', formatter: 'select',
                    edittype: 'select',
                    editoptions: {
                        value: scannamenlijst,
                        //defaultValue: 'Intime',
                        multiple: true
                    },
                    stype: 'select',
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq', 'ne'],
                        value: scannamenlijst,
                        attr: { multiple: 'multiple', size: 4 },
                        dataInit: dataInitMultiselect
                    }
                },
                { name: 'responsedatum', index: 'responsedatum', width: 165, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'd/m/Y H:i:s' }, sorttype: 'date' }
            ],


            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            pager: '#pager',
            loadonce: true,
            gridview: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: 'responsedatum',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            caption: "Scanrespondenten",
            height: '100%',
            beforeRequest: function () {
                modifySearchingFilter.call(this, ',');
            }
        });
        $grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, {
            multipleSearch: true,
            multipleGroup: true,
            recreateFilter: true
        });
        $grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: myDefaultSearch });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...
Silly mistake I used mtype: 'POST' instead of mtype:'GET'