# jqgrid multiselect filter issue with grid refresh

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-ui-multiselect

I was checking the [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simplelocalgridwithsearchingtoolbarmultilpe1.htm) to implement Multiselect filtering in my project.

It is a nice demo indeed but has some issues with it.
Select a filter and hit the refresh button then filters are not resetting. And after that it will starts malfunctioning.

### Select a filter:

[image: Select a filter]

### After hitting refresh:

Filters are not resetting
[image: After hitting refresh]

### Now unchecked the filter:

[image]
Got empty grid.
[image: Now unchecked the filter]

How can I fix these issues? Any Idea.

Comment: Any update/suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report! There are a bug in `clearToolbar` in [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.custom.js#L263-L269) of the code. I will report the bug later to trirand.

To fix the problem one have to use `beforeClear` callback of `filterToolbar`:

```js
beforeClear: function () {
    $(this.grid.hDiv)
        .find(".ui-search-toolbar .ui-search-input>select[multiple] option")
        .each(function () {
            // unselect all options in <select>
            this.selected = false; 
        }
    );

    $(this.grid.hDiv)
        .find(".ui-search-toolbar button.ui-multiselect")
        .each(function () {
            // synchronize jQuery UI Multiselect with <select>
            $(this).prev("select[multiple]").multiselect("refresh");
        }
    ).css({
        width: "98%",
        marginTop: "1px",
        marginBottom: "1px",
        paddingTop: "3px"
    });
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1__.htm) demonstrates the workaround. If the bug in jqGrid will be solved then one could remove the first tree lines from the `beforeClear` callback like in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1_.htm).

Comment: This code is working for jqGrid v4.6.0 but not going to work jqGrid  v4.4.1.
I got a observation(v4.6.0): if I click 'x' to clear the filter I am not getting proper filtered results.
So, How can I remove 'x' from filtertoolbar.

Comment: @Avijit: To remove clear button "X" one needs to use `clearSearch: false` search option. Searching toolbar structure of old jqGrid (4.4.1 for example) is changed. One should change selector `".ui-search-toolbar .ui-search-input>select[multiple] option"` to `".ui-search-toolbar th>div>select[multiple] option"`. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1__441.htm).