# JQGrid MultiSelect Filter option populate based on column's distinct value

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using JQGrid with Multiselect filter to filter individual columns.
Currently I am populating filters(e.g. SkillCategory column) using database master values

```
{
 name: 'SkillCategory', index: 'SkillCategory', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, stype: 'select',
  searchoptions: {
  clearSearch: false,
   sopt: ['eq', 'ne'],
    dataUrl: 'HttpHandler/DemandPropertyHandler.ashx?demprop=skillcat',
    buildSelect: createSelectList,
     attr: { multiple: 'multiple', size: 4 },
     position: {
      my: 'left top',
         at: 'left bottom'
        },
     dataInit: dataInitMultiselect
      }
    },
```

This approach is populating all available master list(for SkillCategory) in to filter.
I would like to show only available filter value based on those are present in available rows for particular column(for SkillCategory).
This should show "Programming" and "Data" as option for SkillCategory filter as rows contains only "Programming" and "Data" value for that column.

[image]

[image]

I found below code(sorry forgot the link)

```
getUniqueNames = function (columnName) {
            var texts = $("#listTableSupply").jqGrid('getCol', columnName), uniqueTexts = [],
            textsLength = texts.length, text, textsMap = {}, i;
            for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
                text = texts[i];
                if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
                    // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
                    textsMap[text] = true;
                    uniqueTexts.push(text);
                }
            }
            return uniqueTexts;
        }
        buildSearchSelect = function (uniqueNames) {
            var values = ":All";
            $.each(uniqueNames, function () {
                values += ";" + this + ":" + this;
            });
            return values;
        }
        setSearchSelect = function (columnName) {
            $("#listTableSupply").jqGrid('setColProp', columnName,
                    {
                        searchoptions: {
                            sopt: ['eq', 'ne'],
                            value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames(columnName)),
                            attr: { multiple: 'multiple', size: 3 },
                            dataInit: dataInitMultiselect
                        }
                    }
        );
        }
```

Calling setSearchSelect("SkillCategory")

```
....  caption: 'Supply',
                emptyrecords: "No records to view",
                loadtext: "Loading...",
                refreshtext: "Refresh",
                refreshtitle: "Reload Grid",
                loadComplete: loadCompleteHandler1,
                ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                    jQuery(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow', rowid);
                },
                beforeRequest: function () //loads the jqgrids state from before save
                {
                    modifySearchingFilter.call(this, ',');
                }
            }).jqGrid('bindKeys');
            $('#listTableSupply').bind('keydown', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) e.preventDefault();
            });
            setSearchSelect("SkillCategory");
            $('#listTableSupply').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerSupply', {
                cloneToTop: true,
                refresh: true, refreshtext: "Refresh", edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false
            }, {}, {}, {}, {
                multipleSearch: true,
                multipleGroup: true,
                recreateFilter: true
            }); .....
```

But seems its not working. Only "All" value is populated.
[image]

Any idea how can I achieve this.

### Update1:

As per Oleg's suggestion below is the working code which worked for me.

```
initializeGridFilterValue = function () {

            //jQuery("#listTableSupply").jqGrid('destroyGroupHeader');
            setSearchSelect("SkillCategory");

            jQuery("#listTableSupply").jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
                stringResult: true,
                searchOnEnter: true,
                defaultSearch: myDefaultSearch,
                beforeClear: function () {
                    $(this.grid.hDiv).find(".ui-search-toolbar .ui-search-input>select[multiple] option").each(function () {
                        this.selected = false; // unselect all options
                    });

                    $(this.grid.hDiv).find(".ui-search-toolbar button.ui-multiselect").each(function () {
                        $(this).prev("select[multiple]").multiselect("refresh");
                    }).css({
                        width: "98%",
                        marginTop: "1px",
                        marginBottom: "1px",
                        paddingTop: "3px"
                    });
                }
            });
            jQuery("#listTableSupply").jqGrid('setGridHeight', 300);
        }
```

And setting it from loadComplete event like below:

```
function loadCompleteHandler1() {
            initializeGridFilterValue();
        }
```

Comment: @Oleg: Just now I have realized "var texts = $("#listTableSupply").jqGrid('getCol', columnName)" only give Page1 value not all pages value.
Is there any way to get full column value.

Comment: Got the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991350/jqgrid-get-all-value-for-a-particular-column-irrespective-of-paging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you use the code from [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935). About your problem: I suppose that you first call `filterToolbar` which creates the filter toolbar and only later you call `setSearchSelect` which set new `searchoptions.value` property. Another possible problem is that you call `setSearchSelect` **before** the data will be loaded in the grid. If you use `datatype: "local"` with `data` parameter then the data are filled in the grid during creating of the grid. If you use `datatype: "json"` then you should first load the data from the server and then call `setSearchSelect` and `filterToolbar` inside of `loadComplete`. For example if you use `loadonce: true` then you can test the value of `datatype` parameter inside of `loadComplete`. If the value is `"json"` then you made initial loading of the data. So you should call `setSearchSelect`, then if required call `destroyFilterToolbar` and finally call  `filterToolbar` to create filter toolbar which selects will have all required values.

Comment: I am using "json" and have updated my code. Worked as expected.
I have a small query: Is it possible to recalculate filters value from an external button?

Comment: The most easy way would be to use `destroyGroupHeader` to destroy the filter toolbar and then create the toolbar one more time using `filterToolbar`. In case of usage Multiselect pluging you can change the options of `<select>` which will be just hidden by Multiselect plugin and call `.multiselect("refresh");` (like in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26949859/315935)).

Comment: What I meant is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980793/jqgrid-multiselect-filter-option-populate-based-on-columns-distinct-valuepart

Comment: I thing we need to use 'destroyFilterToolbar' instead of 'destroyGroupHeader'. This worked for me...:)