# JQGrid get all value for a particular column irrespective of paging

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using "json" to pull data from db.
How can I get all value for a particular column.

I want to get all value/full set of value for "PrimarySkill" column irrespective of paging.

```
var texts = $("#listTableSupply").jqGrid('getCol', 'PrimarySkill');
```

This code only giving me a subset of "PrimarySkill" i.e. giving me the value those are in current page.

I want full set value.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have pure server side grid (with `datatype: "xml"` or `datatype: "json"` and you don't use `loadonce: true`) then jqGrid have no information about the data of other pages as the current page.

If you use local grid or remote grid where the server returns *all data at once* (`loadonce: true` are used) then the data are saved in internal `_index` and `data` parameters of jqGrid. So you can get the data using

```
var mydata = $("#listTableSupply").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"),
    myPrimarySkill = $.map(mydata, function (item) { return item.PrimarySkill; });

alert (JSON.stringify(myPrimarySkill));
```

If you need to have the data in the format `{id:rowid, value:cellvalue}` (like `getCol` with `true` as the second parameter) then the code could be like the following

```
var mydata = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"),
    ids = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "_index"),
    myPrimarySkillWithIds = $.map(ids, function (index, key) {
        return { id: key, value: mydata[index].PrimarySkill };
    });

alert (JSON.stringify(myPrimarySkillWithIds));
```

Comment: Your answers are very perfect and very descriptive.
I am using local grid which fetches data from server in "json" with  loadonce: true.

Comment: @Oleg: thanks, your answer is great. However, I have 1 question. I read your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328072/can-jqgrid-support-dropdowns-in-the-toolbar-filter-fields/5329014). If I want to make `getUniqueNames` function working with this (get data from all pages), how can I re-write the `getUniqueNames` so that it still accept `columnName` as a parameter?

Comment: @Forte_201092: You need just get `$grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` and get `columnName` property of all data instead of  `grid.jqGrid('getCol',columnName)` used in `getUniqueNames`.

Comment: @Oleg: `getUniqueNames = function(columnName)`, in this function, `columnName` is a string passed in to know which column to get data. But because it's a string, we cannot write something like `item.columnName` to get data, right? I just want to make the function generic. As your code above, we only get the column named `PrimarySkill`. I want the column name to be passed as a variable.

Comment: @Forte_201092: You need just make a loop or to use `jQuery.map` for example. If you have problems with implementation you can ask separate question where you describe the problem exactly. I would post the corresponding `getUniqueNames` in my answer.

Comment: any suggestion if the data are not from local data?

Comment: @AdiyatMubarak: If the data are not local then **have jqGrid the information only about the current page**. It send request to the server (to `url`) on changing of the page number or changing of the page size. So one have to make **separate custom Ajax request to the server** to get the data for the column from all pages.

Comment: @AnhTriet - would you mind posting your solution for getting this to work with the `getUniqueNames` function? I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: @FastTrack: yes, it's easy. Instead of writing `item.columnName`, we use `item['columnName']`. Pass the string name in the bracket. For more information, you can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Comment: @AnhTriet thanks! I tried that by doing `var texts = $.map(mydata, function (item) { return item['columnName']; });` however `texts` is always of length `0`. Even though `columnName` is a varialble (one of the parameters of `getUniqueNames`) when I change `columnName` to an actual column name, it works great! Did you have the same trouble?

Comment: @FastTrack: sorry, I didn't go that way, so I didn't have that problem :)

Comment: @AnhTriet no worries, I got it corrected... I just had to remove the single quotes inside the brackets (can't believe I didn't notice that earlier!). So it looks like `item[columnName]`. Thanks for your help! And thanks also to @Oleg for the initial answer.