# Multiselect filter is not working with jqgrid 4.8.2

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, multi-select

I am looking for multiselect filter in jqgrid and I found the following demo from Oleg.

[Demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1_.htm)

When I use jqgrid 4.6.0 js version multiselect filter is working fine but when I use jqgrid 4.8.2 js version, mutliselct filter was displayed with one option selected, When I check the code, I found out attribute 'multiple="multiple"' is not appending to select to filter toolbar.

Can anyone help me in this

Comment: The below solution worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226590/jqgrid-multiselect-filter-not-able-to-filter-multiple-options

Answer (score 0):

I remind me about the bug. It was fixed in free jqGrid. Sorry, but I could not find the exact reference to the bug fix. You can examine [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1__48.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351287/315935). I recommend you to try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.9-RC1. I will publish release of free jqGrid 4.9 probably at the weekend. To test free jqGrid you can just temporary replaces the URLs of jqGrid files (css and js) which you use. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit) for details.

Comment: @user1268130: It seems that I do found [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26949859/315935) which described very close problem. It could be the problem with integration of multiselect plugin. You can examine the code and decide yourself whether it's the same problem which you have or another one.

Comment: In the code which you have given has searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
                        value: "true:Yes;false:No",
                        attr: {multiple: "multiple", size: 3},
                        dataInit: dataInitMultiselect
                    } But attr multiple: multiple is not displaying when it come to display of jqgrid

Comment: @user1268130: Sorry, but I can't follow you. You can see that one can select **multiple** items in multiselect plugin and jqGrid filter correctly based on the choice. If you would **remove** multiselect plugin then you will see the standard `multiple: multiple` which is not comfortable. The goal of multiselect plugin is converting the standard `<select multiple="multiple">...` to more comfortable GUI. The original select will be hold hidden. You can use Developer Tools of the web browser to examine multiselect plugin. You will find the original `<select multiple="multiple">...` hidden

Comment: Even if I removed the multiselect plugin, it will display as single select in the filter toolbar.

Comment: @user1268130: Sorry, but I suppose that we speak about different things. I commented two likes in the demo which I referenced and [the resulting code](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1__48_.htm) uses only `<select multiple="multiple">` like you can directly see. If it's not so you should write: which web browser and in which version you use in your tests?