# Pre-select filters in jqgrid (multi-select)

Tags: jqgrid

Taking this example (http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe.htm) from this question ([Excel like filtering in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869819/excel-like-filtering-in-jqgrid))

Is there a way to set the filter parameters from the start? For example, in the 'Shipped via' column, I would want 'TNT' and 'Intim' to be checked, leaving 'FedEx' unchecked.

One solution I thought was viable is to ship_via

```
if(id == 'gs_ship_via'){ 
                        _.forEach($options, function(option){
                            if(option.value != 'FexEx'){
                                option.selected = true; 
                            } else {
                                option.selected = false;    
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

The problem I run into after that is that it doesn't update the data in the grid. So, I need a different way to set the check box after it's loaded in a way that will update the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you need to include trigger of `change` event (`$("#gs_ship_via").change();`) or to call `triggerToolbar` (`$grid[0].triggerToolbar();`). The exact solution can heavy depend on the place where you made the changes. If you would make the changes of multi-select options for example *after* initializing of multiselect you could see wrong multiselect options and you could require to call `refresh`.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1__48.htm) which displays the results like

[image]

Probably one can modify [the solution](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1_48.htm) for setting multiple values which uses the idea from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884755/315935), but it will take a little more time as I have currently. :-(

Comment: The .change and .triggerToolbar seem to do the trick. Thanks!