# Free jqGrid multi-select from filter bar

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I saw this [free-jqGrid 4.13.4 multiselect toolbar filter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230450/free-jqgrid-4-13-4-multiselect-toolbar-filter-not-working)

and didn't quite understand what is the overall status of this feature in the latest Free jqGrid.

I saw there is a piece of code that is not generic (in the example, it reference 'ship_via' column hardcoded).

I wonder if there is an built-in option to let jqGrid handle ALL the ENUM columns automatically with multi-select support.

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. The demo from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40236912/315935) demonstrates *how* one can use `sopt: ["in"]` operation in combination with the old Multiselect widget. You can easy modify the demo (the code of `beforeProcessingHandler1`) to use Multiselect in multiple columns. The demo don't specify any ENUM columns. It just set `stype: "select"` for some specific column, where one need to use multiselect (with `setSearchSelect.call(this, "ship_via", data);`). One can do the same for multiple columns. Do you tried to do this and found some problem?

Comment: The example is not working for me for some reason.   The initMultiselect is not being called.  I can't publish an example.

Comment: My question was:  jqGrid knows the model, and as such also knows what are the valid attributes for ENUM (what you refer as editType, stype = select), and as such the method getUniqueNames in the example seems redundant.   What I think would reallyhelp here is a new attribute within the colModel, something like multiselect=true that when set, jqGrid takes care for everything.

Comment: Do you mean that [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/MultiselectIn.htm), created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40236912/315935), not work on your computer? Which web browser you use? The method `getUniqueNames` is required to generate `searchoptions.value` dynamically without duplicates. Multiselect is not a part of jqGrid code and thus it could be no special option `multiselect: true`, which will start Multiselect widget for searching in the column.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  Yes, your demo is not working for me.  I suppose I'll need to do some more debug to figure out why.

Comment: It's very strange because [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/MultiselectIn.htm) works at me in all web browsers (Chrome 55, Firefox 50.1, IE 11, Microsoft Edge 38 and even in Vivaldi 1.6).  Let me know if I could help you.

Comment: Sorry Oleg, I meant to write it's not working when I'm trying to apply it on top of my implementation.